# Next value prediction using LSTM or other methods?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, lstm, random-forest

I have a csv file with many patients' health measurement data. Each patient has a different number of measurements. (Some patients come frequently, some don't.) I am trying to do a next value prediction model to predict the patients' risk of specific incidences.
Since the values are all in time sequence, I've tried to use LSTM to make predictions. Also, I am concatenating all the patients' health data together into a long column. (Please see attachment)

[what I am feeding into the LSTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFnMY.png)

And my LSTM model generates results like stock price prediction.

[kind of like my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeZzG.png)

But I wonder if there are better ways. I think my current method of concatenating all my patients' data is strange. Since all the patients have a different number of measurements, I am not sure if can feed them to the LSTM model in parallel. Or maybe I should use random forest because each patient's data has unique distribution? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the different lengths of your data, you can use Padding and Masking to make your data evenly lengthed ([Description of Padding/Masking with Tensorflow)](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding). Predicting sequence based data using LSTMs is generally a good way, but I would advise you to look in GRUs instead of LSTMs and also into Transformer architectures, becuase by now they have many advantages to LSTMs.

Comment: Thank you! I am also confused about how I can evaluate my model. Since I am doing next value prediction, there are no labels or classes to calculate accuracy. The only way to know model performance seems to be the loss values. But what counts as good loss values? Or are there other ways to evaluate my model?

Comment: For this I would advise you to look at this link https://towardsdatascience.com/sequence-to-sequence-labeling-with-recurrent-neural-networks-5405716a2ffa and also get to know the term of Sliding Window algorithm to create correct labels. During training, the model should also give you its accuracy, which can be used to evaluate model performance. Remember to seperate your data into training and test data to correctly evaluate model performance and avoid overfitting.
If this answers your question, please remember to mark this as the correct answer.